# Terraform data "external" provider receive an empty JSON

Tags: powershell, terraform

I am trying to use terraform`s data "External" provider to paste data from Powershell script.
Powershell script returns Azure SQL database name and Edition in appropriate format which then can be used by data external provider.

maint.tf

```
data "external" "my_data" {
  program = ["powershell", "./../tools/GetSqlDBs.ps1"]
}
output "sql" {
    value = local.decoded_data
}
locals {
#   json_data = data.external.my_data2.result

  decoded_data = {
    for key, value in data.external.my_data.result : key => jsondecode(value)
  }
}
```

GetSqlDBs.ps1

```
$resourceType = "Microsoft.Sql/servers"
$resourceNameFilter = "dr02*"

$sqlServers = Get-AzResource -ResourceType $resourceType | Where-Object { ($_.Location -eq "northeurope") -and ($_.Name -like $resourceNameFilter) }

$databasesFullInfo = @()
$databaseInfo = @()

foreach ($sql in $sqlServers) {
    $databases = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $sql.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $sql.Name | `
    Where-Object { ($_.DatabaseName -ne "master") -and ($_.DatabaseName -notlike "*sqldw") -and ($_.DatabaseName -like $resourceNameFilter) }
    $databasesFullInfo += $databases
}

$databasesFullInfo | ForEach-Object {
    $dbInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name    = $_.DatabaseName
        Edition = $_.Edition
    }
    $databaseInfo += $dbInfo
}


#### DEBUG ##################################

# $dbInfo2 = [PSCustomObject]@{
#         Name = "Object 1"
#         Value = 42
#     }
# $databaseInfo += $dbInfo2

# $dbInfo3 = [PSCustomObject]@{
#         Name = "Object 2"
#         Value = 123
#     }
# $databaseInfo += $dbInfo3
#############################################

$databaseInfoMap = @{}
foreach ($db in $databaseInfo) {
    $databaseInfoMap[$db.Name] = $db | ConvertTo-Json
}

$jsonOutput1 = ""
# Convert the hashtable to JSON-formatted string
$jsonOutput1 = $databaseInfoMap | ConvertTo-Json

# Output the JSON string
$jsonOutput1
```

[image]

Powershell script works correctly if I run it manually and produces the output below.
However data external provider does not get it:
[image]

But if I uncomment debug section then data "external" provider gets only two objects from debug section and produces the output without databases:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

This workaround solve the problem if I add this code to my GetSqlDBs.ps1.
But how to avoid this in production environment?

```
$login = ""
$password = ""
$tenantId = ""
$subscriptionId = ""

$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $login, $userPassword


# # Authenticate to Azure
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId $tenantId -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Credential $userCredential | Out-Null

# # Set the Azure subscription context
Set-AzContext -TenantId $tenantId -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId | Out-Null
```

Comment: Still looking for a solution how to pass environment variables with clientid, secret, tenant and subscriptionid to data "external" provider to be able then pass it to PS script